# Infinite sum of cardinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I'm studying set theory and met with the following problem: Let set $E=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ be of cardinality $\aleph_1$; show that one of $A_i$ must also have cardinality $\aleph_1$.

I've come up with a proof using basic definitions. But I heard from a friend a very short proof via cardinality arithmetic:

> Suppose each $A_i$ has cardinality $<\aleph_1$. Clearly they cannot all be countable. Therefore, we have
> $$
> \aleph_1=\operatorname{card}\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right)\leq\operatorname{card}\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty\bigcup_{a\in A_i}(i,a)\right)\color{red}{\leq}\aleph_0\times\max_i\operatorname{card}(A_i)\leq\max_i\operatorname{card}(A_i)\times\max_i\operatorname{card}(A_i)<\aleph_1,
> $$
> which is a contradiction.

**Is the proof correct?** I don't believe in this proof myself because I highly doubt the validity of the less-or-equal sign marked red.

**Edit:** I find this less-or-equal sign correct now, because there's clearly an injective function from $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty\bigcup_{a\in A_i}(i,a)$ to $\mathbb N\times\operatorname{argmax}\operatorname{card}(A_i)$. However, the proof is incorrect, since we are not sure whether there is a maximum cardinality among $\operatorname{card}(A_i)$. Henno Brandsma also points out some important points here (see comments).

Comment: The cardinal after $\color{red}{\le}$ should simply be $\aleph_0 \times \aleph_0 = \aleph_0$ as we can estimate each $\operatorname{card}({A_i})$ by $\aleph_0$. "Clearly they cannot all be countable" is *false*, it's exactly what follows if you assume $\forall i \operatorname{A_i} < \aleph_i$. In fact that's where we get our contradiction from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if $\operatorname{card}(A_i) < \aleph_1$ we know $\operatorname{card}(A_i) \le \aleph_0$. So if the conclusion would **not** hold **all** $A_i$ would be at most countable but then $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ would also be at most countable which is a contradiction with it having cardinality exactly $\aleph_1$.
That's all.

Comment: Yes, if the first statement is true then the problem is quite easy. But we are not allowed to use the continuum hypothesis here.

Comment: @JeffreyWang We're not using CH: $\aleph_1$ is **by definition** the *first/smallest* *uncountable* ordinal, so having a strictly smaller cardinality than $\aleph_1$ implies immediately that it must be at most countable.

Comment: @JeffreyWang The continuum hypothesis says that $\operatorname{card}(\Bbb R)= \aleph_1$ but we're not talking about the size of $\Bbb R$ here. CH is irrelevant.

Comment: Hmm... CH states that there is no set whose cardinality is strictly between that of the integers and the real numbers. I assume that your first statement follows from this. If not, then how? Thanks :)

Comment: @JeffreyWang From minimality of $\aleph_1$ as I said!

Comment: @JeffreyWang: The $\aleph$ numbers are defined independently of $\Bbb R$ the other sets.